# Difference between google material library and design support library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I was trying the new material design components on android such as the bottom app bar but i discovered that every MDC was existing in the android design support library but also in another library called `com.google.android.material` and the code was pratically the same (in the design library the code was documented unlike the other), so what is the difference between these two library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html) post `com.google.android.material` is a replacement for old support library.

> Additionally, following the introduction in 28.0.0-alpha1 of Material
>   Components for Android as a drop-in replacement for Design Library, we
>   have refactored the design package to reflect its new direction.

Comment: So what library should I use?

Comment: @Andrea, use com.google.android.material if possible

Comment: "...(AndroidX) which represents a new era for the Support Library" not "com.google.android.material"

Answer (score 2):

More detail from there:

https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate

> AndroidX maps the original support library API packages into the androidx namespace. Only the package and Maven artifact names changed; class, method, and field names did not change.

Old artifact: `com.android.support:design`

New artifact: `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01`